# Bootstrap tabs not working in dropdown collapse

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So here is my code:

```
<ul class="nav" data-tabs="tabs">
                 <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#despre" >Despre Documentatie</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#constitutia" >Despre Documentatie</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#despre" >Despre Documentatie</a></li>
               <li class="dropdown">
                   <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1">Legis <b class="caret"></b></a>
                   <ul id="collapse1" class="collapse">
                       <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#constitutia">Constitutia</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Conceptul de lege</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Hotararea</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Ordonanta</a></li>
                       </ul>
               </li>

<div class="tab-content" id="my-tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="constitutia">
        {% include 'juristdoc/legis/constitutia.html' %}
                    </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tap-pane" id="despre">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h1>Bine ati venit!</h1>
                    <p>Documentatia juridica este locul in care va puteti informa in legatura cu actualitati juridice.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

I added the first 3 li's for testing and they are working switching back and forth, but after I click on one of the tabs from the collapsed list, it's not working. For example if I click on #despre and then on #constitutia from the dropdown class, it's working but then if I try to switch back and forth again it's not.

Comment: It looks like your missing an ending </ul> tag or am I missing something?

Comment: It's there, I haven't copied that part. After more testing I have reached the conclusion that tabs are very unstable